# Is it possible to use an XML file as a dependency in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am working on a project that uses an XML file to pull in a number of attributes that dictate how my application will behave. The XML file can and will change over time because the attributes in the file help tune our application for certain cases.  We would like to have Maven pull this versioned XML in and place it where we need it in our build.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maven Remote Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/)

This plugin is used to retrieve JARs of resources from remote repositories, process those resources, and incorporate them into JARs you build with Maven. A very common use-case is the need to package certain resources in a consistent way across your organization: at Apache it is required that every JAR produced contains a copy of the Apache license and a notice file that references all used software in a given project.

Edit:

1) If the xml file locates in file system instead of another jar or aggregated source such as a zip file or something else you can simply use [resource section](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) at your pom. It can simply include this xml file in your project output as war or jar or etc..

2) But I believe that this is the not good way you should prefer. If the file is not depending on file servers, use maven assembly plugin to create an aggregated resource and use maven remote resource plugin to fetch it.

3) If all of these strategies are not suitable for you, simply put these xml file in file system where your project is working and your project can use it from file system instead of your jar files. Whenever you need to change it, change it and reload your system.

Answer (score 1):

This is just what the `/src/main/resources` directory is for, it will automatically include whatever is in there in the resulting `.jar` or `.war` in the `classpath`. This is described in the [standard layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) documentation.

As for versioning, just use your standard version control that the rest of your project is using.

Comment: The Java library that I'm using needs to have the XML file in the same directory as the main executable JAR.  Also, we want to have the XML file used as a dependency that would be pulled from our repository because it is being changed weekly, if not daily.

Comment: Maven is only for packaging up what you want as a `.jar`, `.war`, etc., anything **outside** the package is **your** problem and nothing that Maven can do about it.

Comment: @Edward Kennedy. Senator, it's easy enough to make your install script to unpack a single xml file from jar into its main directory (You somehow still need to put your main jar file there).  Putting it under the source control in the project that produces that main jar will make sure that it IS a dependency of that project.

Comment: 1) Where is this xml file? 2) can you put at in another jar and so you can version it?